# geomintersects function limit

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, geometry, expression

I am using `geomintersects` in QGIS and there is, unfortunately, a limit for feature test of this function (100000  test).

Is there a way to exceed this limit to take more than 100000 test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Open user profile folder ("Settings > User profiles > default").
- Goto `/python/plugins/refFunctions`.
- Open `refFunctions.py`.
- Go to `geomintersects` function definition. Change `100000` in `if count < 100000:` to a value that you desire.

You need to do same process for the other functions, if you want to use them.